# Bootstrap reordering of columns not working (specific case)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have 2 columns and three rows, there is some text in some of the boxes and some images in the others.

so for example on mobile screens this is what I have:

A 
B 
C
D
E
F

When I put it on a bigger screen now I get:

A B
C D
E F

But on bigger screens I want:

A B
D C
E F

So D&C swap. I have tried using col-xs-push-6 and col-xs-pull-6, but it still doesn't seem to work. As you can see in the snippet, when i put it back into mobile form it doesn't do what I want.

```css
.row{
  width:30px;
  height:100px;
}

.col-xs-6{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6 ">A</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 ">B</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-push-6">D</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-pull-6">C</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 ">E</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 ">F</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read this https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#push-and-pull... you are using wrong classes..

Comment: You should not use the alpha or beta versions of Bootstrap 4 any more as the release version is out for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the [Ordering utility](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/#order) classes of Bootstrap 4, I think this is the simplest possible markup for this one:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 ">A</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 ">B</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 order-md-2">C</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">D</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 order-2">E</div>
        <div class="col-md-6 order-2">F</div>
    </div>
</div>

<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the flexbox ordering classes:

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/xCHIz7D17v (alpha6)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 flex-md-first">A</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 flex-md-first">B</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 flex-md-last">C</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 flex-md-first">D</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 flex-md-last">E</div>
    <div class="col-md-6 flex-md-last">F</div>
</div>
```

Alpha 6 is unstable, and **4.0.0 has been released**. In this latest version, the [ordering classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#order-classes) are now `order-*`

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/FBlK8JJ3Ax (**4.0.0**)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at flex-container and the order property

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div style="order: 3">1</div>
  <div style="order: 2">2</div>
  <div style="order: 4">3</div> 
  <div style="order: 1">4</div>
</div>
```

You could also add a media@ query to set the order property depending on the width or height